# Get selected item from a ListBox at hold

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I've got a ListBox in a WP7 App where I want to do something with an item when the user hold it. The event work's great. My hold method gets called, but I can't detect which element in the list was hold. 
ListBox.SelectedItem is always -1 and a code from another post on stackoverflow doens't work:

```
FrameWorkelement element = (FrameworkElement) e.OriginalSource;
ItemViewModel item = (ItemViewModel) element.DataContext;
```

I get an InvalidCastException when running it in the second line.

Answer (score 5):

The following code should work.

```
private void StackPanel_Hold(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    ItemViewModel itemViewModel = (sender as StackPanel).DataContext as ItemViewModel;
    string t = itemViewModel.LineOne;
}
```

Note: before using the DataContext of the sender object, make sure you cast the sender object to the correct class. In this example I use a StackPanel in my DataTemplate:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Height="78" Hold="StackPanel_Hold">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```